# What isn't right with logging in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I have configured logger for different channel in different files, but it does not work for me. It's work but it writes in console not in pointed file.
And I need write log to file in channel search.
Here is my code:

```
#app/config/config_dev.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        search:
            type: stream
            level: error
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/search_log.log"
            channels: [search]
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: [!event, !search]
        console:
            type:   console
            channels: [!event, !doctrine, !search]
```

Defined service:

```
#MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    app.logger_search:
            class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger
            arguments: ["@logger"]
            tags:
                - {name: monolog.logger, channel: search}
```

Now use it service, try to test it:

```
#MyController.php

/**
 * @Route("/test")
 */
public function test()
{
    $this->get("app.logger_search")->error("Test");

    return $this->json("test");
}
```

But it writes into console insted of file. 
Console I meant where I ran my server: `php bin\console server:run`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Creating your own Channel**. This is done either via the [configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/channels_handlers.html#configure-additional-channels-without-tagged-services) or [by tagging your service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#monolog-logger) with `monolog.logger` and specifying which channel the service should log to (just as you have done).

Both ways are valid and in both cases you logger will be named:

```
monolog.logger.<you-channel-name>
```

So use `monolog.logger.search` instead of your service id `app.logger_search` to fix the issue.

I you don't have a strong reason to change the logger behavior, I suggest to [configure additional channels without tagged services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/channels_handlers.html#configure-additional-channels-without-tagged-services):

```
# app/config/config.yml
monolog:
    channels: ['foo', 'bar']
```

With this, you can now send log messages to the `foo` channel by using the automatically registered logger service `monolog.logger.foo`.

Comment: as I understood I need to create new instance for each channel in my class?

For example:
private $loggerSearch;
private $logger;
Or I can do it something another way?

Comment: Likely you should do it in another way. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ok, and if I will use it wat how can I give the unique pth to log file for each channel?

Comment: "how can I give the unique pth to log file for each channel?" I do not understand the question, what do you mean? Please, add another separate question if it's not related.